# Checking if a Metal vertexBuffer is null in MTKMesh

Tags: swift, macos, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to draw an `MTKMesh`. To do this, I will need to set bind vertex buffers before executing the draw call. The documentation for MTKMesh.vertexBuffers is as follows:

```
/**
 @property vertexBuffers
 @abstract Array of buffers in which mesh vertex data resides.
 @discussion This is filled with mesh buffer objects using the layout described by the vertexDescriptor property.  
             Elements in this array can be [NSNull null] if the vertexDescriptor does not specify elements for buffer for the given index
 */
open var vertexBuffers: [MTKMeshBuffer] { get }
```

So my understanding is that I need to iterate over this array, and bind a vertex buffer for every non-null element. I have this code so far:

```
    for (bufferIndex, vertexBuffer) in mesh.vertexBuffers.enumerated() {
        if (!(vertexBuffer is NSNull)) {
            renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer.buffer, offset: vertexBuffer.offset, index: bufferIndex)
        }
    }
```

However, it doesn't seem to work as I get the following warning:

> Cast from 'MTKMeshBuffer' to unrelated type 'NSNull' always fails

I also tried this:

```
        if (vertexBuffer != nil) {
            renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer.buffer, offset: vertexBuffer.offset, index: bufferIndex)
        }
```

But this also doesn't seem to work work, as I get the warning:

> Comparing non-optional value of type 'MTKMeshBuffer' to 'nil' always returns true

How can I iterate over the non-null elements of this array?

Answer (score 1):

`class MTKMeshBuffer` is a subclass of `NSObject`. Apparently the declaration

```
open var vertexBuffers: [MTKMeshBuffer] { get }
```

is “lying” – the array elements can be pointers to `MTKMeshBuffer` instances *or* to `NSNull` instances. That is no problem in Objective-C because one can freely cast between different types of object pointers, and something like

```
for (MTKMeshBuffer *vertexBuffer in mesh.vertexBuffers) {
    if (![vertexBuffer isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        //
    }
}
```

compiles without warnings in Objective-C.

The Swift compiler does not accept this “lie” so easily: You have to cast the `MTKMeshBuffer` pointer to a `NSObject` pointer (the common superclass of `MTKMeshBuffer` and `NSNull`) before you can test for the actual type:

```
for (bufferIndex, vertexBuffer) in vertexBuffers.enumerated() {
    if !(vertexBuffer as NSObject is NSNull) {
        // ...   
    }
}
```

Alternatively one can use the Objective-C `isKindOfClass` method, which is imported to Swift as `isKind(of:)`:

```
for (bufferIndex, vertexBuffer) in vertexBuffers.enumerated() {
    if !vertexBuffer.isKind(of: NSNull.self) {
        // ...   
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope this is correct – it compiles without warnings, but I cannot *test* it currently.

Comment: I'm quite far off being able to render anything so I'm also currently unable to test this but it looks good and will come back and accept if it works.

Comment: @konsolas: Did you have a chance to test it?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still unable to test this as there appears to be some kind of bug in MetalKit, where instead of inserting NSNull in `vertexBuffers`, to pad each buffer out to the correct index, the nulls aren't included at all and the vertex buffers that are present are just in the wrong indices.

Comment: (So essentially MetalKit is not currently giving me any `vertexBuffers` with NSNull that I might be able to test this on)